# dplyr 0.5: arrange() using groupings

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I've got a lot of code written in dplyr 0.4.3, that relied on the grouped arrange() function. As of the 0.5 release, arrange no longer applies grouping.

This decision baffles me, as this makes arrange() inconsistent with other dplyr verbs, and surely a user could just ungroup() before arrange() if ungrouped is required. I would have hoped for perhaps a parameter in arrange() to retain grouped_by behavior, but alas!

I therefore have to rewrite my grouped arrange. At this point, my only option seems to be to break up the pipe at the arrange call, loop through the groups and arrange group by group, and then bind() the result again. I'm hoping there might be a more elegant solution?

Below is an MRE, I'd like to run a cumsum on wt per group_by(cyl). Many thanks for ideas/suggestions.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  arrange(desc(mpg)) %>%
  mutate(WtCum = cumsum(wt))
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to `arrange` before grouping?  Based on running your code using `0.5.0`, i get the 'mpg' arranged descendingly within each group of cyl

Comment: @akrun - goodness, you are correct, and thank you. In which case, I obviously misunderstood the [release notes](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/releases). How do you interpret the first note: "arrange() once again ignores grouping"

Comment: Things don't look in order by `cyl` to me if I `View` the whole dataset at the end of the pipe.  It's close, but that is because number of cylinders is highly related to mpg.  To arrange within groups, add the grouping variable inside arrange.  For this example it would look like `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% arrange(cyl, desc(mpg))`

Comment: Thanks @aosmith - that is perfect! If you'd convert your comment to an answer, I'd be able to select it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To order within groups in dplyr 0.5, add the grouping variable before the other ordering variables within `arrange`.

```
mtcars %>% 
       group_by(cyl) %>% 
       arrange(cyl, desc(mpg))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep around an “old `arrange`”, you may use [this snippet](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1206#issuecomment-229902087):

```
arrange_old <- function(.data, ...) {
  dplyr::arrange_(.data, .dots = c(groups(.data), lazyeval::lazy_dots(...)))
}
```

This will respect grouping by basically prepending the group variables to the new `arrange` call.

Then you can do:

```
mtcars %>% 
    group_by(cyl) %>% 
    arrange_old(desc(mpg))
```

For what it's worth, I've also found this change confusing and unintuitive, and I keep making the mistake of forgetting to explicitly specify the grouping.